# Jquery Masonry not accommodating different heights

Tags: jquery, css, image, grid

I'm currently trying to get jquery masonry to accomodate with different image heights, but it is not wanting to work.

CSS:

```
  #container {
    background-color:red;
    width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .item {

    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    width:275px;
    background-color:red;

}
```

Jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 275
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="item"><img src="/green"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="/purple"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="/green"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="/green"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="/purple"></div>

<div class="item"><img src="/green"></div>
 </div>
```

In an ideal world, the two purple squares would be beneath each other.

Interestingly, if I remove the jquery masonry, nothing changes.

Comment: Maybe try fixing your HTML document and see if that helps. Your STYLE tag should be within the HEAD and you have no closing HEAD tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the HTML problems I mentioned in my comment above and also load jQuery before loading the jQuery Masonry file that should hopefully fix your problems.

My previous comment:

Maybe try fixing your HTML document and see if that helps. Your STYLE tag should be within the HEAD and you have no closing HEAD tag.